# How do I calculate Tax for a Long Term Capital Gain?

Tags: united-states, irs, calculation, capital-gain, schedule-d

Do I calculate tax based on IRS tax tables on page 65 (or worksheet on page 77, 110) of https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf

Or

Do I calculate tax based on Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet (page 36) of https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf

I bought 2 year note for $100, and got discount of $10.

1099-B says

**Long-Term Covered Securities**

**Applicable Check Box on Form 8949:** D

**Proceeds (Ref Box 1d):** $100

**Cost or Other Basis (Ref Box 1e):** $90

**Type of Gain or Loss: (REf. Box 2):** Long-term

**Check if basis reported to IRS (Ref. Box 12):** X

Then I read Form 8949, Part II https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8949.pdf

> You must check Box D, E, or F below. Check only one box. If more than
> one box applies for your long-term transactions, complete a separate
> Form 8949, page 2, for each applicable box. If you have more long-term
> transactions than will fit on this page for one or more of the boxes,
> complete as many forms with the same box checked as you need.

I check Box D

> (D) Long-term transactions reported on Form(s) 1099-B showing basis
> was reported to the IRS (see Note above)

I see Note Above

> Note: You may aggregate all long-term transactions reported on Form(s)
> 1099-B showing basis was reported to the IRS and for which no
> adjustments or codes are required. Enter the totals directly on
> Schedule D, line 8a; you aren’t required to report these transactions
> on Form 8949 (see instructions).

From what I understand, **I don't need to file Form 8949** because I can put totals on Schedule D, line 8a

I file Schedule D, line 8a, https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sd.pdf

I enter $10 on line 15

> 15 Net long-term capital gain or (loss). Combine lines 8a through 14
> in column (h). Then, go to Part III on the back . .

I enter $10 on line 16

> 16 Combine lines 7 and 15 and enter the result • If line 16 is a gain,
> enter the amount from line 16 on Form 1040, 1040-SR, or 1040-NR, line
> 7. Then, go to line 17 below.

Ok, I go to line 17

> 17 Are lines 15 and 16 both gains? Yes. Go to line 18. No. Skip lines
> 18 through 21, and go to line 22.

Both 15 and 16 are gains so I go to line 18

> 18 If you are required to complete the 28% Rate Gain Worksheet (see
> instructions), enter the amount, if any, from line 7 of that worksheet

What is this 28% Rate Gain Worksheet. No, I am not required to fill.

I go to line 19

> 19 If you are required to complete the Unrecaptured Section 1250 Gain
> Worksheet (see instructions), enter the amount, if any, from line 18

What is this Unrecaptured Section 1250 Gain Worksheet. No, I am not required to fill.

I go to line 20

> 20 Are lines 18 and 19 both zero or blank and are you not filing Form
> 4952? Yes. Complete the Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax
> Worksheet in the instructions for Forms 1040 and 1040-SR, line 16.
>
> Don’t complete lines 21 and 22 below.

The answer is YES. 18 and 19 are both zero or blank. And I don't even know what this 4952 form is?

I understand that I must complete Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax
Worksheet in the instructions for Forms 1040 and 1040-SR, line 16.

HOWEVER

When I read 1040 instructions for Line 16 (on page 30), it says

> If you don’t have to file Schedule D, use the Qualified Dividends and
> Capital Gain Tax Worksheet in the line 16 instructions to figure your
> tax.

Wha??????

But I HAVE TO file Schedule D. Schedule D says

> Complete the Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax
> Worksheet in the instructions for Forms 1040 and 1040-SR, line 16.

Which one is it?????????

Comment: Not sure what your confusion is. You are asked to complete the worksheet in the instructions, so do that.

Comment: "if you don't have to file Schedule D, complete the worksheet" does not imply that "if you have to file Schedule D, don't complete the worksheet". Rather, if you have to file Schedule D, Schedule D tells you what you need to complete. In this case, Schedule D tells you to complete the worksheet.